# How to architect a single modal component accessible by multiple components in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react and I'm having trouble getting my head around the architecture of my app.  Here's what I've got:
I use `fetch()` to get an array of records (`records`) from the backend.  I use a couple of custom components to handle outputting the data.  At the end of the tree is a series of touchable components which I need to open a single modal component on press.  Here's a simple version of the code:

./app.js

```
<ScrollView>
    {records.map((record, index) => {
        return <Post key={index} post={record} />
    })}
</ScrollView>
```

./src/components.js

```
function Post(props) {
    return (
        <Child info={props.post} />
        ...other custom components in here...
    )
}

function Child(props) {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => ...open modal...}>{props.info}</TouchableHighlight>
    )
}
```

So I can't put my `<Modal>` in either of the components in `components.js`, as then I end up with one modal for each record in the database.  So I figure I need to put it at the end of the `<ScrollView>` in `app.js`, but then how do I open and close it from the `<Child>` component?  I've read that it's possible to pass info back up the chain to a parent component using a callback function, but I'm unsure of how to do that while also passing props down that contain the information of each record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this logic:

```js
const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(false);

const handleVisibility = () => {
  setModalVisible(!modalVisible)
}
return(
 <View>
  <YourWrappingModalComponent visible={modalVisible} />
   <ScrollView>
    {records.map((record, index) => {
        return <Post 
                 key={index} 
                 post={record} 
                 handleVisibility={handleVisibility} />
                 })}
  </ScrollView>
 </View>
)
```

To open modal from `Child` you do:

```js
function Post(props) {
    return (
        <Child info={props.post} handleParentModal={props. handleVisibility} />
        ...other custom components in here...
    )
}

function Child(props) {
    return (
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => props.handleParentModal()}>{props.info}</TouchableHighlight>
    )
}
```

Using a component like `YourWrappingModalComponent` where you define your modal is very useful if you use your modal in many places.

Comment: Can you expand on that a little?  How do I open the modal from the `<Child>` component?

Comment: ok i will edit the answer. If this helps plz check and +1. Thanks